# Плавная перерисовка Image

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать чтобы при смене Image Source картинка плавно сменялась на новую?

```
 <Image Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" 
           Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    </Image>

public ImageSource CurrentImage
        {
            get
            {
                _currentImage = null;
                _currentImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_listImageUri[_currentIndex]));
                return _currentImage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Расшифруйте фразу "плавно выезжала".

Comment: 2 Image друг над другом, верхний плавно меняет Opacity с 1 до 0. Или используйте [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, можно небольшой пример по WriteableBitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = /*Чё нить*/;
new WriteableBitmap(System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                                    myBitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                                    IntPtr.Zero,
                                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()));
```

или

```
new WriteableBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/myImage.png")));
```

Перезапись картинки (изменение):

```
WriteableBitmap wb = /*Допустим тут уже есть данные*/;
Bitmap myBitmap = /*тут новая картинка*/;
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmd = 
    newBitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height), 
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
wb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, newBitmap.Width - 1, newBitmap.Height - 1), bmd.Scan0, bmd.Stride * bmd.Height, bmd.Stride);
newBitmap.UnlockBits(bmd);
```

В Вашем случае новая битмапа - это новая картинка + поверх неё нарисованная старая с некоторой прозрачностью. На след.шаге прозрачность увеличиваем. ну и до тех пор, пока полностью старая картинка не исчезнет. Пихаем эту логику в таймер.